# Does opcache.revalidate_freq apply when opcache.file_cache_only=1?

Tags: php, opcache

I am running PHP7.2 with opcache enabled. Due to PHP running as FastCGI without any process manager (such as PHP-FPM) I am forced to use the file only opcache which I have set with

`opcache.file_cache_only=1;`

I have also set

```
opcache.validate_timestamps=1;
opcache.revalidate_freq=180;
```

My understanding with these settings is that the opcache checks no more frequently than every 180 seconds if a file has to be re-processed. In other words, if I upload a new version of a PHP file to the server it would in general not be immediately available in its new version, because the opcache would still use the prior version. But after 180s seconds the new one should be processed.

However, it appears that the opcache immediately re-processes any new version. So it looks like the `revalidate_freq` setting is ignored in the case of `file_cache_only=1`.

Can somebody confirm this? Is there documentation about this? Or is the opcache not working properly at all? I do see the new php.bin files in the .opcache directory. So at the very least it is being processed, but I do not understand why it does this immediately and not after 180 seconds.